# Java regex - First needs to be the letter X(case insensitve) the rest digits

Tags: java, regex

I need to match to see if a string is in the format of X[d].... It has to have the letter X (case intensive) at the start and AT LEAST 1 digit after. I tried the following regex, but it doesn't matchanything:

```
 ^(?i)[x](?=.*[0-9])*$

   // ^(?i)[x] - first character needs to be x (case intensive)
   // (?=.*[0-9]) - should have at least one digit after and must be all digits after
```

Comment: *it doesn't matchanything* is actually wrong, see below. It matches `x` or `X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you may use

```
s.matches("(?i)x[0-9]+")
```

It will match a string starting with `x` or `X` and then having 1 or more digits.

You should not quantify a lookahead, a zero-width assertion, since it would mean it would match an empty location and matching it repeatedly means you are still there and the regex index is not advanced.

However, *Java regex just ignores a quantified lookahead*.  Your current regex, `^(?i)[x](?=.*[0-9])*$`, matches `x`  but not `x5` as there is only one part to match, `[x]`. see the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/2Ppl2r).

Even if you remove the `*` quantifier, `^(?i)[x](?=.*[0-9])$` does not match any string since `$`, end of string, is required right after `x` while `(?=.*[0-9])` positive lookahead requires a digit after any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following.

```
^(?i)x\d+$
```

This translates to case insensitive x followed by one or more digits 0-9. There's no need for brackets around the x because it's not a set. It's only one character.

Alternatively, you can create a set that consists of upper and lower case x.

```
^[xX]\d+$
```